# How to create zoom fit google map marker?

Tags: javascript

i am had some trouble in google map marker fit Zoom.i am get the latlng data dynamically in Xml format.

here this my code.i need some help pls any one help.

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('user_type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));


            // var res = point.split({lat: lng:});

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');


          text.textContent = address//address view
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
             var icons = ["http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png",
                        "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"
                         ];



            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            //icon:icons[i],
            icon:icons[Math.floor(Math.random()*icons .length)],
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38803725/6634591). Maybe this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fitBounds()` method:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

//extend the bounds for each marker that you add
bounds.extend(marker1.getPosition());
bounds.extend(marker2.getPosition());

//update the map to fit the bounds
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```